# abc() takes 33 positional arguments but 35 were given

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, object

There is a python 3.7 file like the following

```
class FraudIncremental():

    def run(self):
          html = self.make_html_email(self.overview, start_date, end_date, url,
                                      url2, url3, url4, url6, url5, url7, url8, url9,
                                      url10, url11, url12, url15, url16, url17, url18, count_one_device,
                                      count_fulfillment, count_sum2, count_sum1,
                                      count_7, count_lonely, count_patrol, count_disputes,
                                      count_clear, count_decline, count_dfg, count_settle20, count_country, count_abc, cfg)


    def abc(self, overview, start_date, end_date, url, url2,
                        url3, url4, url6, url5, url7, url8, url9,
                        url10, url11, url12, url13, url14, url15, url16, count3, count4,
                        count5, count6, count7, count8, count9,
                        count10, count11, count12, count13, count14, count15, count16, cfg):
        rules = self.parse_df(overview, cfg)
        amounts= self.parse_df_sum(self.counts)
        counted = self.parse_df_count(self.counts)

        template_vars = {
            "startdate" : start_date,
            "enddate": end_date,
            "rules": rules,
            "url": url,
            # remove "urlN": urlN, (where N=2~15), OTHERWISE stackoverflow thinks the post contains mostly codes
            "url16": url16,
            "count3": count3,
            # remove "countN": countN, (where N=4~15), OTHERWISE stackoverflow thinks the post contains mostly codes
            "count16": count16,
            "amounts": amounts,
            "counted": counted
        }
        html_out = make_html(template_path = "xyz",
                             template_vars = template_vars)

        return html_out
```

When I ran this code, there is an error message:

```
abc() takes 33 positional arguments but 35 were given
```

I am really confused because abc() should take 35 arguments in this case? What is missing?  Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling the function?

Comment: function abc() you mean?

Comment: Show us what you're running in order to have that error pop up. Whatever lines it takes for me to copy/paste that into a terminal to reproduce it for myself.

Comment: And this is why passing <strike>33</strike> 35 params to a method is a bad idea.

Comment: Look at `self.overview` vs. `self, overview`

Comment: This really should make you pause and re-evaluate some choices: url, url2, url3, url4, url6, url5, url7, url8, url9, url10, url11, url12, url13, url14, url15, url16, count3, count4, count5, count6, count7, count8, count9, count10, count11, count12, count13, count14, count15, count16. The counts start at 3, and the URLs aren't even in order!

Comment: I know it is a bad choice.  I actually just started to maintain the codebase @digitalarbeiter

Comment: Consider using lists or tuples and checking their length using `len` at the start of the function.

Comment: @Chubaka In that case I wish you perseverance, patience, and the best of luck. May you succeed where others failed!